# I want to display value of field having more than 70 characters

Tags: oracle

I want to display values of a field having more than 70 characters in oracle database. No of characters count I have but I want to view values for a field having more than 70 characters

Comment: If you are using Oracle database, why have you tagged postgresql?

Answer (score -1):

Use `"CHAR_LENGTH"` function.This function return the length of string.

e.g:

```
select field_name from table_name where CHAR_LENGTH(field_name)>70;
```

or

```
select field_name,CHAR_LENGTH(field_name) 
from table_name where CHAR_LENGTH(field_name)>70;
```

This one show the number of character from field.

Comment: Hi Thank for your reply

Comment: When I execute query I get error ora-00904 "CHAR_LENGTH" : INVALID IDENTIFIER